# Subtracting date by one and obey calendar correctly

Tags: perl

Im attempting to subtract the day by one with localtime, but I also need it to obey the monthly format.

For example, let's say it's July first, my program will need to display data from June 30th with localtime, but if I subtract the date by 1 it's not going to be helpful.

```
   my $minutes_back = 4;
   my $dt     = localtime( time - $minutes_back * 60 );
   my $date_from=sprintf("%d/%d/%d",$dt->mon,$dt->mday,$dt->year);
```

Does anyone have a better way, other than me storing the current date and doing an eval if it's the first then backtrack to the previous month?

Comment: Calendar math is insanely complicated. Some days are 25 hours long (depending on the time zone). Once in a while, there are 61-second minutes. There seem to be more edge cases than hairs to pull out in a fit of frustration. Let's rather stick to widely used, stable modules for that. [`DateTime` with the `subtract_duration` method](https://metacpan.org/module/DateTime#dt-subtract_duration-duration_object) and [`DateTime::Duration`](https://metacpan.org/module/DateTime::Duration) would be worth checking out.

Comment: Have a look at [perlfaq4](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.16.2/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-find-yesterday%27s-date?) for computing yesterday's date.

Comment: Use the DateTime module.  It will do the right thing for you.  The number of rules that you are unaware of is staggering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl stores datetimes as the *number of seconds since the Epoc*. *The Epoc* is usually January 1, 1970 because that's the very first day the world was created.

Then, Perl provides an interface that helps you convert the internally stored datetime into time you can actually use.

Since Perl 5.10, Perl comes with the [Time::Piece](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html) and [Time::Seconds](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Seconds.html) modules.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw(say);

use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds;

my $time = Time::Piece->new;   #Uses current date by default
$time -= ONE_DAY;
say $time->mdy("/");
```

Of course, you don't have to use the current *datetime*. You can use `Time::Piece->strptime` to use whatever time you're interested in:

```
my $date = "2013-Jan-01";   #Any format is fine
my $time = Time::Piece->strptime( $date, "%Y-%b-%d");
$time -= ONE_DAY;
say $time->mdy("/");  # Prints 12/31/2012
```

The `%` formats are found in the [strftime](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime) webpage.

Answer (score 0):

This code returns date of previous day from current day.Not sure whether you are looking for this.I was using this for a non-critical simulator, so I wasn't worried about corner cases if any.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;
use POSIX;

printf("%s\n",TimeStamp2Date(Date2TimeStamp('2013-07-01') - (1*24*60*60))); 
# Prints date of previous day.

sub     Date2TimeStamp
{
    if($_[0]=~/(\d\d\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d)/)
    {
        my @Temp=split(/-/,$_[0]);
        my $Stamp=mktime(0,0,01,$Temp[2],$Temp[1]-1,$Temp[0]-1900,0,0,-1) ;
                         #Seconds #Minutes #Hours   #Day     #Month     #Year      
        return($Stamp);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Error:Invalid date format\n");
        getc();
    }
}

sub     TimeStamp2Date
{
    my @temp = localtime($_[0]);
    my $time = join('-',reverse(sprintf("%02d",$temp[3]),       # Day
                                sprintf("%02d",$temp[4]+1),     # Month(0-11)
                                sprintf("%04d",$temp[5]+1900)));# Year since 1900
    return("$time");
}
```